# Do natives use "to be" to describe future tense?

Tags: passive-voice, future-tense

> [Any data **to be** processed by this application is suggested to be kept
>   under this directory.](http://deepdive.stanford.edu/deepdiveapp)

I found the sentence shown above on Stanford University's website. I would like to know whether the following sentence differs in meaning from the sentence above.

> Any data **that is/will be** processed by this application is
>   suggested to be kept under this directory.

Comment: Your use of **that is** does not mean the same thing and doesn't sound right; meanwhile, your use of **will be** makes the sentence ungrammatical.

Comment: The original sentence is a mouthful. It would be much less awkward if it read: *It is suggested that any data to be processed by this application be kept under this directory.**